# Data that is posted from angular 4 is getting as null in .net core web api

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angular, .net-core

As part of learning i was working on creating a angular form and connecting it to a web api,when i post data from form,it is getting as null values in the api, I have tried adding a [Route("jsonbody")] but that is not working, also tried `JSON.stringify(model)` in the service but that is also not working.

This is how i posted the data from angular

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
   this.registerobj.postUserData(this.model).subscribe()
 }
```

Model class is

```
export class UserModel {
constructor(
    public FirstName: string ='',
    public LastName: string = '',
    public Address: string = '',
    public DateOfBirth: string = '',
    public Gender: string = '',
    public Language: string = '',
    public Email: string = ''
) {}
}
```

Posted the data from service like this

```
postUserData(model: UserModel) {
     return this.http.post<any>(`${this.serviceUrl}`, model)
}
```

.Net Core api Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        public UserController(IUser userItems)
        {
            UserItems = userItems;
        }
        public IUser UserItems { get; set; }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Insert(UserModel user)
        {
            UserRepository UserItems = new UserRepository();
            try
            {

                if (user == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Recieved a Bad request");
                }
              UserItems.Add(user);

               return Ok();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, e);
            }

        }
    }
```

UserModel in API

```
 public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: .NET Core uses PascalCasing by default. Your Angular model uses PascalCasing. Have a look if that helps... Please also catch the actual call (network tab in debugging tools) to see if the request looks like it should. And you could use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to get the call to work first, so you can fix it in code later.

Answer (score 1):

try by sending  the data in body like this.

```
post(data) {
           const body = {
                  "column_name1":"data1",
                 "column_name2":"data2",

       };
       const headers = new Headers(
            {
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post(this.url, body, options).map((response: Response) => response.json());
```